# Where to store assessment name/type in Clinical Impression Resource?

Tags: hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir

I’m currently working on an implementation that facilitates the flow of data, from clinical record(s) into a personal health record.

We are planning to use the FHIR ClinicalImpression resource for routine planned heath reviews and it seems to be a good match. 
These reviews are part of a standard care plan, have specific names/types to differentiate them and have a form with a set questions, tests, findings and follow up for the health professional to fill out with the patient.
Looking at the ClinicalImpression resource I see no property for (a) location where the assessment took place and (b) the name/type of the assessment.

This seems an oversight. Should these be implemented using extensions?

We see investigations[0]/code as inappropriate, because the name / type of the assessment relates to all of the information in the clinical impression

Any comments, suggestions or feedback would be most welcome.

Thanks in advance,

Bob.

Answer (score 0):

ClinicalImpression is still draft, so it may be missing important pieces of information.  Feel free to submit a change request proposing the addition of these elements.  In the meantime, extensions would have to be your solution.  (Location could also be captured via Provenance.)